# Given $y = x^3 − 2x$ for $x \geq 0$, find the equation of the tangent line to $y$ where the absolute value of the slope is minimized.

Tags: optimization

I tried finding the derivative of this, and promptly got $y=$ about $0.816$, but I have no idea how to put that into equation form or if I'm even correct.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  What do you get for the slope of the tangent line at $x$?

Comment: Did you mean $\color{red}x\approx0.816$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you already got $y' = 3x^2 - 2$. This is the slope of the curve $y$.

As per the question, you need to find absolute minimum of the slope which in
this case is $0$ for $x = \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$, (where $x \ge 0)$.

Substituting x in your curve, you get the equation of the tangent line as the slope is zero.

$y + \frac{4\sqrt2}{3\sqrt3} = 0$